# Zend Framework Zend Zend_Form_SubForm Label

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

Been looking for a while on how to sort this out.  Essentially, I just need to set a label for a Zend Framework Sub Form.

However I try to do this is just doesn't work.  Zend Sub Form doesn't have a Label attribute so you can't seem to set it.  However, when the form renders, you can clearly see a DT tag inwhich the label should go:

```
<dt id="password_form-label">&nbsp;</dt>
```

I have tried everything, and it seems like quite a normal thing to be able to do.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try using LEGEND...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Legend isn't really what I need.  I did look into it and got it working. 

In fact I have it working now.  It took quite a bit of work.  In the end I extended Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper and Zend_Form_SubForm.

If anyone needs an explanation, please contact me.